# Install specific package version through meta-package

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I have a meta-package for `tensorrt` which is just a list of dependencies to specific versions of libraries. Here is the `control` file of it:

```
Package: tensorrt
Source: tensorrt (7.1.3-1+cuda10.2)
Version: 7.1.3.4-1+cuda10.2
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: cudatools <cudatools@nvidia.com>
Installed-Size: 11
Depends: libnvinfer7 (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvinfer-plugin7 (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvparsers7 (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvonnxparsers7 (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvinfer-bin (= 7.1.3-1+cud
a10.2), libnvinfer-dev (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvinfer-plugin-dev (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvparsers-dev (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvonnxparsers-dev (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvinfer-samples
 (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2), libnvinfer-doc (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2)
Section: multiverse/devel
Priority: optional
Description: Meta package of TensorRT
 Meta package of TensorRT.
```

Now, when I want to install `tensorrt` it says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tensorrt : Depends: libnvinfer-dev (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2) but 8.0.3-1+cuda11.3 is to be installed
            Depends: libnvinfer-plugin-dev (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2) but 8.0.3-1+cuda11.3 is to be installed
            Depends: libnvparsers-dev (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2) but 8.0.3-1+cuda11.3 is to be installed
            Depends: libnvonnxparsers-dev (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2) but 8.0.3-1+cuda11.3 is to be installed
            Depends: libnvinfer-samples (= 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If we take a specific lib, for example `libnvinfer-dev`, according to `apt-cache policy`, I have several versions of it available:

```
(ubuntu-xenial-amd64)svc_moma_usr@PL1LXD-529389:/$ apt-cache policy libnvinfer-dev
libnvinfer-dev:
  Installed: 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2
  Candidate: 8.0.3-1+cuda11.3
  Version table:
     8.0.3-1+cuda11.3 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
     8.0.3-1+cuda10.2 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
     8.0.1-1+cuda11.3 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
     8.0.1-1+cuda10.2 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
     8.0.0-1+cuda11.3 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
     8.0.0-1+cuda11.0 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
     8.0.0-1+cuda10.2 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
 *** 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2 500
        500 https://repository.ttgroup.com/repository/rozbad-xenial xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.0.0-1+cuda10.2 500
        500 file:/var/nv-tensorrt-repo-cuda10.2-trt7.0.0.11-ga-20191216  Packages
        500 https://repository.ttgroup.com/repository/rozbad-xenial xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

As you can see, I managed to install the version I want explicitly with `apt install libnvinfer-dev=7.1.3-1+cuda-10.2`, even though the version is older, but installing this version is not possible through `tensorrt` meta-package, although the older versions are also explicitely stated there. How can I make APT install this package?

I know that it is possible to change the priorities in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`, but this is done on the system level, while I want to tell APT to install these packages through the `control` file.

Comment: You can't, not just using your meta package's dependency settings

Comment: How about some workaround? For example, I know I can install the dependencies manually with a specific version. When in the debian package files (control. rules, etc) I could add bash command in which I install the packages, and not with the dependency resolution mechanism.

Comment: That won't work either, since the package management system is locked while an installation is in progress, so installation commands in the maintainer scripts will fail. You can provide a script to install your package which can then do things like `apt-get install meta-pkg=x.y dep1=a.b dep2=c.d`, etc., or put all dependencies in your repo and add that repo with a high pin priority.

Comment: Thanks. But I could run the bash commands containing `apt-get ...` before the installation. I didn't mention this originally, but I need to install `tensorrt` to build another package using `sbuild` and installation of `tensorrt` was triggered from `debian/control`. Maybe I could run these `apt-get` commands before installation of tensorrt is triggered, but I am not quite sure about the order in which `sbuild` steps are run. My idea was to override sth. in `debian/rules`